# Tags list on user profile

Tags: support, tagging, profile-page

> Can someone point me to a reference for what the tags list is for on a user's profile?

From what I understand, if you ask a question, the tags on that question are added to the list, but the multiplicity of each tag only corresponds to votes on answers you've given. Is this correct? If not, could someone please clarify. If it is correct, can someone please explain why we list tags corresponding to questions and answers together if we are only going to count the votes on one but not the other?

Comment: You can hover over those numbers and get pretty much the same information as in Asaf's answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[image]

[image]

Comment: I think the $\times 132$ is the number of posts total, including questions and CW. If you hover over 549 in your profile you can see that you posted 123 non-CW answers for which you received 549 upvotes; you [asked 5 questions](http://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A17762+%5Breal-analysis%5D+is%3Aquestion) and you [wrote 4 CW-answers](http://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A17762+%5Breal-analysis%5D+wiki%3A1) in (real-analysis).

Comment: @Martin Thanks. Have updated accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

It's the list of tags in which the user participated. The score is the aggregated score of all non-wiki answers in the particular tag. The number in the multiplier is the number of all non-wiki posts (questions and answers) in that tag.